# Windows 8.1 keeps detecting old uninstalled graphics card so I can't upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I'm on Windows 8.1, the Windows 10 upgrade tool detected that my old nvidia 7600 was too old to upgrade to Windows 10.

So I installed a newer card, an nvidia 210. I removed nvidia drivers and reinstalled them.

Device manager shows new card correctly. However the Windows 10 upgrade tool shows my old nvidia 7600 and says it can't upgrade. When I click view report, it says it last ran a few weeks ago (I just installed the new card today).

How can I get it to detect my new card?

I've tried manually running scheduled task:

```
schtasks.exe /Run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"

SUCCESS: Attempted to run the scheduled task "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser".
```

Comment: Did you uninstalled the device from device manager and uninstalled the drivers before you physically removed it from the system?  I suggest you just go ahead and proceed with the upgrade and skip the compatibility appraiser.

Comment: Ok thanks, yes stupidly I physically removed the device before removing it in windows. I didn't know that I could go proceed with the upgrade and skip the compatibility check.